# Align form text at baseline of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do something like the following, but I can't figure out how to align the logout link *just above* the navigation bar, without specifying an explicit `padding` or `line-height` which breaks the layout if the size of the image changes.

[image]

```
<img src="logo.png" />
<a> logout link </a>
<div> navigation bar </div>
```

I am using bootstrap, but I am also fine with a non-bootstrap solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thanix says, you can combine relative and absolute positioning to achieve this. Make a containing div for the image and the logout link so that the logout link can be set at the bottom of this.

```
<div class="header">
    <img class="logo_image" src="logo.png" width="40" height="40" /> 
    <a class="logout_link"> logout link </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav_bar">navigation bar</div>
```

Then make the containing div position:relative and the logo position:absolute. The trick here is that "an absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static." (www.w3schools.com). This means you can use bottom:0px and right:0px to position it at the bottom right of the containing div.

```
.header {position:relative;}
.logout_link {    
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.logo_image {
    float:left;
}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

The class="clear" div at the end of the containing div is to make sure the containing div fills the space of its child components.

Comment: PS the float:left of the logo image is optional, it just makes sure there is no vertical gap between the image and the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the logout `<a>` inside the navigation bar `<div>`.
2. Set navigation bar's `position` to `relative`.
3. Set logout's `position` to `absolute`, `right` to `0` and `top` to `-1em`;